# Google Chrome Extention in Blazor

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, blazor, blazor-client-side

As Blazor can run on client side via WebAssembly, can we develop/design Google Chrome extensions using Blazor?

Comment: Not yet... sadly

Answer (score 11):

I have developed a package to be able to build a Blazor WebAssembly application into a chrome extension.

Checkout the repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/mingyaulee/Blazor.BrowserExtension) for a step by step instruction how to convert your project to a Blazor chrome extension project.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this Github repo that demonstrates a Hello World Chrome Extension written in Blazor. It has no interaction with Chrome APIs but does show how to package up a Blazor app as an extension.

https://github.com/traxium/webassembly-chrome-extension

You should be able to use Javascript Interop to call browser APIs, but I don't know of any way to call them directly.  An open source project that mapped the browser APIs to C# would be ideal here.

Answer (score 1):

Yup! We can develop/design Google Chrome extensions using Blazor-webassembly-app.
I'm building a chrome extension using asp.net 5.0 in blazor-webassembly-app.

I have faced so many difficulty till now and right now I am continuously facing difficulty its because no one in the world tried it yet and I am researching on it while building my POC (proof of concept).

[image]
[image]

Comment: and i forgot to give credit to a nice developer guy named @jsakamoto. I was stuck on the start and he helped me in another version of blazor-chrome-extension POC. means my other POC was about how to inject my whole blazor-extension into a webpage. Although I didn't success on it but for the moment it is on hold.
You can find #jsakamoto on twitter and github for further help in future.